# Homology over $\mathbb{Q}$ using Gaussian elimination for differential matrix boundary operators

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology, principal-ideal-domains, gaussian-elimination

The Smith normal form of an integer matrix $A\in\text{Mat}_{m
\times n}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a factorization $A=UDV$ for:

- $D\in\text{Mat}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{Z})$
- Each diagonal entry of $D$ divides the next, i.e. $d_{i,i}|d_{i+1,i+1}$ (elementary divisors of $A$)
- $U\in\text{Mat}_{m\times m}(\mathbb{Z})$, $V\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{Z})$ are invertible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Denote by $a_1,\dots, a_r$ the non-zero elementary divisors of $A$ for $r=\text{rank}(A)$. Then given a complex $\mathbb{Z}^n\overset{A}\to\mathbb{Z}^m\overset{B}\to\mathbb{Z}^k$ (where $BA=0$), the homology at the middle is given by $\ker(B)/\text{im}(A)\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^r\mathbb{Z}/a_i\oplus\mathbb{Z}^{m-r-s}$ for $s=\text{rank}(B)$.

> Is there a similar result where we instead consider homology over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ using Gaussian elimination on $A$?

Comment: Yes. It's basically repeated applications of the rank-nullity theorem. You don't have the torsion part anymore. All that matters is the rank of B and A.

Comment: No, @Multivariablecalculus, just $ker(B)/im(A) \cong \mathbb{Q}^{m-r-s}$.

Comment: Ah, thanks again! @OmarAntolín-Camarena